# Iterate over files in folder, rename them and switch the nth occurence of a character with another character

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I need your help trying to understand how I could combine some actions to get to the expected results.
So i have the following path, in which I have many files:

```
/home/application/Upload_Actions/TestFiles/
```

Now, the files have the following name:

```
DATE20220703.2130_Network=MainPipeline,Action=Upload_File,Element=X988Schema_1000_statsfile.csv
```

What I want is to iterate over all the files from within that folder, and replace the `_` from its name with `:`.
The file should look like:

```
DATE20220703.2130_Network=MainPipeline,Action=Upload_File,Element=X988Schema:1000_statsfile.csv
```

I have written a small one line for, but I am not quite sure how to iterate to the NTH occurence of the symbol _.

```
for f in ./*statsfile*; do mv "$f" "${f//_/:}"; done
```

The thing is that it does the following thing:
From:

```
/home/application/Upload_Actions/TestFiles/DATE20220703.2130_Network=MainPipeline,Action=Upload_File,Element=X988Schema_1000_statsfile.csv
```

To: (but it failes doe to NO SUCH FILE or DIRECTORY because it replaces the _ from the path)

```
/home/application/Upload:Actions/TestFiles/DATE20220703.2130_Network=MainPipeline,Action=Upload:File,Element=X988Schema:1000:statsfile.csv
```

How could I do that only the 3rd occurence of the _ symbol gets replaced, so that the _ symbol from the path and the first _ symbol from from the title are left alone?
Expected results:

```
/home/application/Upload_Actions/TestFiles/DATE20220703.2130_Network=MainPipeline,Action=Upload_File,Element=X988Schema:1000_statsfile.csv
```

**OS Version: CENTOS 7**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing the second occurence from the end? Like:

```
for file in ./*statsfile*; do
  head=${file%_*_*}
  tail=${file#"$head"_}
  echo mv "$file" "$head:$tail"
done
```

Remove `echo` to actually move the files.

Comment: worked like a charm. Thank you :) And yea, it was better to replace the second occurrence from the end instead of going for the third or how many I would have had based on the Path :)

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash solution using `read` with `IFS=_` that splits each filename into tokens delimited by `_`:

```bash
cd /home/application/Upload_Actions/TestFiles/
for f in *statsfile*; do
   IFS=_ read -r p1 p2 p3 last <<< "$s" &&
   echo mv "$f" "${p1}_${p2}_${p3}:$last"
done
```

PS: Used `echo` for debugging purpose and you can remove it later after verifying the output.